# Where is the right place to start a topic regarding Microsoft certifications?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What site in the Stack Exchange network (meta/SO/programmers) is the best for starting a topic about a Microsoft certification? I'm not after technical assistance - I would like opinions on being 'ready' for the exam etc.

Comment: Maybe on SO chat?

Comment: OH hey :P Look who it is ;)

Comment: We do not have Forums...and to say it from the beginning: I'm 99.99% sure that it is ***not*** Programmers.

Comment: I don't think that a non programming question would be recieved positively on any of those sites... As you said - "I'm not after technical assistance" perhaps SOFU is not the right place...

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/exam-prep.aspx)?  Let google do the work for you ;)

Comment: @Bobby - what are you being argumentative for? You *know* what I meant by forums.

Comment: @Lix - thanks, but that link doesn't answer any of the questions I'd like from people who have actually done the exam.

Comment: I revised the question so people won't frown over the wording.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474287/microsoft-developer-certification and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387832/microsoft-certifications-mcts-core-exam-70-536-is-the-measureup-practice-test that may allready answer your question, however these days programmer.se is a better place for this type of question then stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Looks like http://programmers.stackexchange.com is the place, quick search gave two related examples:</s>

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94416/is-microsoft-certification-a-waste-for-asp-net-mvc-development-mcts-70-515-and
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91143/ms-certifications-for-non-it-students

Both not technical, both received upvotes and never got closed.

Things have changed in the years that passed. [The other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127816/152859) is correct, such question is off topic for Stack Exchange network these days.

Comment: You should know that past questions can be a bad guide to what's currently on topic on a site. These questions are very problematical as they are very localised and potentially highly subjective.

Comment: @ChrisF they're both less than year old - can't really call them old so I assume if they're off topic there they would have been closed by now.. no?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: You're aware that Chris is Diamond at Programmers?

Comment: @SkonJeet - Please be *very* careful about how you word your question if you do post it on Programmers.

Comment: @Bobby nope.. but still - personally I believe that if such questions exist, have upvotes and not older than a year it means that's the most  proper place in the network. whether the specific question Mr. Jeet is going to ask will be proper or not I can't predict.

Comment: *"Both...never got closed."* ***Challenge accepted.*** ;-)

Comment: @TheEstablishment omg.. please please don't tell them I sent the army! :D

Comment: The first one is now closed... Certification questions are borderline, they have to be _very_ good to survive on Programmers /cc @SkonJeet

Comment: @rene true, done that.

Answer (score 8):

You are asking for "opinions".

This makes the question Not Constructive on *any* site in the Stack Exchange network. These sentences are in *all* FAQs:

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)